# html print variable value

Tags: html, button

Right now I have this code and I would like to print on the screen(not a pop up) the value of how many times the button has been clicked. I think i would set a var index = 0 and increment it each time it is clicked... but I am not sure how to change the variable value on the screen. For instance, right now it has been clicked 0 times. When I click the button I want the value over there <-- (0) to become 1. I might have to put a blank picture in white over it and then reprint the value of index...

Also.. I would like this to be ALL IN HTML.. if possible, no php or javascript please.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getVote(int)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="+int,true);
xmlhttp.send();


if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
  {
  if (localStorage.clickcount)
    {
    localStorage.clickcount=Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
    }
  else
    {
    localStorage.clickcount=1;
    }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="You have voted " + localStorage.clickcount + " times before this session";
  }
else
  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}

</script>

</head>
<body bgcolor=#5D003D>
<div id="poll">

<p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
<p>Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter will continue to count (is not reset).</p><form>
<input type="Button" class="voteButton" name="vote" value="Vote" onclick="getVote(this.value)" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: DEMO, make plunker or jsFiddle! or at least code snippet of SO

Comment: This question is a bit difficult to understand.  Please feel free to add a JSFiddle of your work, but please know that this cannot be done in just HTML, you will most definitely need JS as well.

Comment: I want to be able to fly. But NO AIRPLANES, or wings or man made objects. Sometimes what we want is just not practical though.

Comment: This is not possible with pure HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do it without JavaScript at least. Here's a trivial example. First, I tell the window object to give me a yell when all of the images/scripts/content on the page has loaded. This means that I can be sure that the HTML contained within the body will exist before I try to attach an event-listener to any of the elements it contains.

Next, when I know the content has loaded, I tell the button to let me know when it is clicked.

Finally, when the button has been clicked, I increment the global-variable `pressCount` and then set its value to be the contents of the span element.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', onButtonPressed, false);
}

var pressCount = 0;
function onButtonPressed(evt)
{
    ++pressCount;
    document.getElementById('countOutput').innerText = pressCount;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id='myButton'>PressMe</button> has been pressed <span id='countOutput'>0</span> times.
</body>
</html>
```